# Why angularjs change variables that are different?

Tags: html, angularjs, ajax, angularjs-ng-model, 2-way-object-databinding

I am getting an ajax data from api and saving it to a variable. And I have to "edit and save" or "edit and cancel" changes on this data. I am using ng-model to show and edit this data.

Here is my script:

```
function getData() {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: API + '/api/Educations/UserEducations',
        data: {}
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        vm.UserData = response.data;
        vm.CachedUserData = response.data;
    })
}
```

And here is my html:

```
<div ng-repeat="education in editEducationsCtrl.UserData">
    <div>{{education.SchoolName}}</div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="education.SchoolName">

    <button ng-click="editEducationsCtrl.saveChanges()">Save</button>
    <button ng-click="editEducationsCtrl.cancelChanges()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

When user clicked cancel button, I want to write html cached data.
But,
When I try to access vm.CachedUserData variable, I am seeing this cached data has already changed with new value of vm.UserData... How? I have checked my code there is no function access CachedUserData variable. Even I changed variable name to unique name but result is same.

I want to save first data in a variable. But angular changes both of them. Is 2 way databinding change all variables that connected the same ajax data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use angular.copy() to bind the data you want to cache:

```
vm.UserData = response.data;
vm.CachedUserData = angular.copy(response.data);
```

Comment: It worked, thanks but Html view isn't change when I assign `vm.UserData  = vm.CachedData` . Could you help me in this subject too?

Comment: Not make sense, probably the variable name is wrong, should be 'vm.CachedUserData'?

Answer (score 3):

`=` in JavaScript does not clone the variable, it creates another pointer on it. That means you can handle your variable by using both `vm.UserData` and `vm.CachedUserData`.
It seems you want to clone your variable, so:

**If it is an array:**

```
...
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    vm.UserData = response.data.splice(0);
    vm.CachedUserData = response.data.splice(0);
})
...
```

**If it is an object:**

- `var newObject = jQuery.extend({}, oldObject);` if you have JQuery
- `obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o));` without JQuery

Here is a [good link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object) for cloning objects in JS.

Comment: there is `angular.copy` or `angular.merge` for shallow/deep copy of object.

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks for your comment! :-)

Comment: Thank you. It worked but now I have a different problem. Html view isn't change when I assign `vm.UserData = vm.CachedData` . Could you please help me in this subject too?

Comment: I think you should provide the code that assign UserData to CachedData (`saveChanges()` function?).
Anyway, you should rather ask another question, this is a different problem from this one.

Comment: Ok then, Thanks a lot.